# AWS SDK for .NET ListBuckets error

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk

I am using the simple AWS SDK for .NET documentation sample, in a c# windows application, in order to list my buckets and I am receiving the error below. I can create buckets and upload files fine but I can not do any listing/getting of buckets/objects? Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

ERROR MESSAGE - There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

ERROR INNER EXCEPTION -  was not expected."

ERROR STACKTRACE - at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)\r\n at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.processRequestResponse[T](HttpWebResponse httpResponse, S3Request request, Type t, T& response, Exception& cause)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.handleHttpResponse[T](S3Request userRequest, HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse httpResponse, Int32 retries, Int64 lengthOfRequest, T& response, Exception& cause, HttpStatusCode& statusCode)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getResponseCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndListBuckets(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ListBuckets(ListBucketsRequest request)\r\n at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ListBuckets()\r\n

//CODE

```
using (AmazonS3 amazonS3 = SetAmazonS3Client())
{
    using (ListBucketsResponse response = amazonS3.ListBuckets())
    {
        foreach (S3Bucket bucket in response.Buckets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You own Bucket with name: {0}", bucket.BucketName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code works fine for me... so I would think the error is something specific to your environment:

- Odd/explicit permissions on the IAM user that your AWS credentials are associated with?
- Nonstandard characters in some of your existing bucket names?
- Old version of the AWSSDK?

Comment: I am using the AWSSDK.dll 1.4.10.0 and the bucket name is just something like dummybucket  How do I look at the permissions of the IAM user via the Google API Console?  I had turned on "Interoperable Access" and generated the access and secret key but I did not know these were associated with a user?